# what's the difference between using object, collection and locals in partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have trouble to understand the difference between

```
<%= render :partial => "book", :object => @book %>
```

and

```
<%= render :partial => "book", :collection => @books %>
```

and

```
<%= render :partial => "book", :locals => { :book => @book } %>
```

Can someone explain it to me  ?

Comment: It's worth noting that you've missed the simplest way to do this: `<%= render @book %>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the same:

```
<%= render :partial => "book", :object => @book %>
<%= render :partial => "book", :locals => { :book => @book } %>
<%= render "book", :book => @book %>
```

They will render the `_book.html.erb` file once, and the @book object will be available in that partial as the `book` variable.

Here is a sweet way to abbreviate the same thing:

```
<%= render @book %>
```

This one is a little different:

```
<%= render :partial => "book", :collection => @books %>
```

It will render the `_book.html.erb` file once per book in `@books`, each in turn becoming available in that partial as the `book` variable.

Here is a sweet way to abbreviate the same thing:

```
<%= render @books %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= render :partial => "book", :object => @book %>
```

Will render the partial `_book.html.erb` setting the local variable `book` to `@book`.

```
<%= render :partial => "book", :collection => @books %>
```

For every element in `@books` will render the partial `_book.html.erb` setting the local variable `book` to the current element in `@books`.

```
<%= render :partial => "book", :locals => { :book => @book } %>
```

Will render the partial `_book.html.erb` setting the local variable `book` to @book.  This form lets you set additional local variable or change the name of them, whereas the :object version does not.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= render :partial => "book", :object => @book %>
```

In the first case using :object will define a variable with the same name as the partial by default. If my partial template is named _user.html.erb then there will be a local variable named "user" defined in the template.

You can specify a different variable name with :as => "another_name".

```
<%= render :partial => "book", :locals => { :book => @book } %>
```

The biggest advantage of the `:locals` is that

1. you have very clear control over the objects and names
2. you can assign more than 1 variable

The disadvantage of the `:locals` approach is that it is more verbose, and sometimes a simple

```
render :partial => 'account'
```

is identical to

```
render :partial => 'account', :locals => {:account => @account }
```

So use the one which suits you the best (or where it suits the best).

```
<%= render :partial => "book", :collection => @books %>
```

For Collection See : http://blogs.visoftinc.com/2010/04/27/ruby-beauty-rendering-a-rails-partial-for-a-collection/

More info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials